# Which is the most optimal way to pass a List < DTO > containing image in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working with a DTO that is sent through WCF from backend to frontend. 
The structure of my DTO is like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id;

    [DataMember]
    public string Image;

    [DataMember]
    public int? Version;
}
```

As you can see we are handling Image as a string. When we retrieve the string from service, we display it in UI using a StringBuilder to build an html section:

```
keyboardHtml.Append("'<img class=\"");
keyboardHtml.Append("' src=\"");
keyboardHtml.Append("data:image/png;base64,");
keyboardHtml.Append(image.Image);
keyboardHtml.Append("\"");
```

We need to get more than 200 images at the same time, if we send all of them in one List < MyDTO > we get the max quota exceeded exception.

In config file binding configurations are:

maxBufferPoolSize="524288"

maxBufferSize="655360"

maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"

So to avoid this error, we are calling the service in chunks of 20 images using an iterator:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfImages; i += 20)
{
    List<MyDTO> listIncomplete = communicator.SendCommand<int, List<MyDTO> ("GetImagesRange", i);
    resultList.AddRange(listIncomplete);
}
```

I'm sure it is completely inneficient. I would like to ask:

1.) Which data type can be used instead of string to send the image in order to make it more efficient?

2.) Which other approaches can be useful to optimize this way of image retrieval?

Additional Note.- These images are stored in the db. 
Thanks in advance. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I would look at using a byte array (`byte[[`) and streaming (or chunking).

Comment: I would also use the byte[], but there isn't a much better way to do it. The only other possibility is to send the path, and if the web site has access to the filesystem it can just read the image. This, of course, doesn't work if you have the image in a database or other binary form instead of on the filesystem, or if you aren't doing server side processing (like ASP).